# add special price to grouped product

Tags: price, bundled-product, grouped-products

I want to create grouped and bundle products, where a bundle and group have a special price that is not sum of prices of all individual products.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6):

Bundled products can be created with a fixed price, after that the special price can be a percentage of that. Using the fixed price will ignore any price changes in the simple products under it.

Grouped products do not offer an option like that. But you can use `Promotions > Catalog Price Rules`. In the conditions tab you can specify the SKU of the product you wish to apply the rule to. After that you can set the promotional price and you're done.

Small side note: having a lot of promotional rules will slow the frontend of your shop down so use them wisely

Comment: But will such promotions push through M2E etc?

Comment: Your condition not working for me, could you pls help me

Comment: @JeevaRathinam best to post a new question with all the details :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to achieve doesn't make too much sense, what if one of the products within the group experiences a dramatic price increase, your bundle product wouldn't then see this change.

I'd just create a discount rule for purchasing the bundle product, it would probably be the simplest way of achieving what you're trying to. `Promotions` > `Shopping Basket Price Rules`

Comment: Makes good sense to me.

Comment: @g-man1066 : i need to add discount for grouped products how can i do that,